# Sort data per date in kibana discover

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I want to filter log dadta per date in kibana discover and this is the only way I've discovered so far

[image]

How can I filter data per date more easily ?

Comment: you can use query instead of filtering

Answer (score 0):

** You can use Range queries**
Range queries allow a field to have values between the lower and upper bounds. The interval can include or exclude the bounds depending on the type of brackets that you use.

for example :
To search for slow transactions with a response time greater than or equal to 10ms:

```
event.duration: [10000000 TO *]
```

To search for slow transactions with a response time greater than 10ms:

```
responsetime: {10000000 TO *}
```